# Is it possible to stream response to Dialogflow CX?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I have been working with implementing GPT responses in Dialogflow CX.

As GPT responses can be made to stream directly as they are generated (creating a "typewriter effect") I wonder if it is possible to direct this stream as a response to Dialogflow. Then the response would be "typed out" in the Dialogflow chat window as it is created.

I have looked at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook), but did not find any suitable endpoint nor method to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to do this currently. Dialogflow doesn't currently have an endpoint or method for streaming responses.

One possible workaround would be to use a third-party service to stream the response to Dialogflow. For example, you could use a service like Pusher or Socket.IO to create a websocket connection between your Dialogflow agent and your GPT agent. Then, you could use the websocket connection to stream the GPT response to Dialogflow.